# Uploading a file via Kendo, Webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, kendo-ui

I want to upload a file via kendoupload and receive the file with webservice. My file might be a quite big file.
Here is my aspx :

```
<input type="file" name="File1" id="File1"   />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class ="k-button" onclick="beginUpload()"/>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
  function beginUpload()
  {
       $("#File1").kendoUpload({
           async: {
              saveUrl: 'GetFile.asmx/ReceiveFile',
              autoUpload: true
          },
          multiple: false
      });
  }
```

Finally here is my webservice:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public  string ReceiveFile(string s)
    {

       return "Hello World!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a file to ASMX isn't supported (not by Kendo UI but in general).